# Can't seem to create file in bash

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell

I'm trying to use this (under the root account) code in debian 7.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa << EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
XYZ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa
```

When I navigate to this folder afterwards it's tells me it doesn't exist. I've checked and double checked but can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: When I run the command manually it seems to work! But I am trying to run this as part of a shell script.

Comment: If you change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` does it show anything more helpful?

Comment: Did you check the permissions on `.ssh` directory?

Comment: The code posted above seems to work fine for me - can you provide the output of `stat /root/.ssh` and `ls -l /root/.ssh`

Comment: Actually you might have found the problem. Does the directory have to exist beforehand? Is there a way to make it create the directory if it doesn't exist in the same commend?

Comment: The directory does need to exist beforehand, `cat` won't create directories. I'll update the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ssh` folder probably doesn't/didn't exist when you first ran the command. The safest thing to do is to add a command before the `cat` that checks/creates the folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /root/.ssh

chmod 700 /root/.ssh
cat > /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa << EOF
<some content>
EOF
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa
```

Comment: .ssh folder does exist yes.